# Overwriting URL parameters in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I'm writing a React Native app and I'm running into a situation as to not knowing how to override/replace parameters on a URL.

In the following URL I would like to replace the HOST and the PORT:

```
axios.get('http://HOST:PORT/dtcmtools/api/mufs/dynsystbls/MFO')
```

I already have the variables, just don't know how to pass them.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options

1. Use axios default url so you don't have to put HOST:PORT every time

   ```
   axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://HOST:PORT';
   ```

   then you can do

   ```
   axios.get('/dtcmtools/api/mufs/dynsystbls/MFO')
   ```
2. Just use template strings if you have ES6 supported

   ```
   axios.get(`http://${host}:${port}/dtcmtools/api/mufs/dynsystbls/MFO`)
   ```
3. Normal concatenation

   ```
   axios.get('http://'+host+':'+port+'/dtcmtools/api/mufs/dynsystbls/MFO')
   ```